# Passing instantiated type into generic parameter

Tags: java

I'm trying to instantiate a number of RPCConsumers based on a list of ConsumerTypes as per below.

The issue is that RPCConsumer will obviously not get types T and R. When the Function apply method is then called, you get a cast exception.

I know I need to pass the types into RPCConsumer - is this where I need to use reflections? I also may be needlessly over-complicating.

TIA

```
public class ConsumerType<T, R> {

    private final RPCQueue queue;
    private final Function<T, R> actionFunction;

    public ConsumerType(RPCQueue queue, Function actionFunction) {
        this.queue = queue;
        this.actionFunction = actionFunction;
    }

    public RPCQueue getQueue() {
        return queue;
    }

    public Function getActionFunction() {
        return actionFunction;
    }

}




 public class RPCConsumer<T, R> extends DefaultConsumer implements Callable<Void> {

    private Channel channel;
    private String queueName;
    private Function<T,R> function;

    public RPCConsumer(Channel channel, String queueName, Function<T, R> function) throws IOException {
        // Constructor
    }

    // METHODS ETC

}

public class RPCConsumerFactory {

    private List<ConsumerType> consumerTypes;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public RPCConsumerFactory(List<ConsumerType> consumerTypes) throws NoHealthyServiceException {
        this.consumerTypes = consumerTypes;
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(consumerTypes.size());
    }

    public void createRPCConsumers() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        for(ConsumerType consumerType : consumerTypes) {
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

            String queueName = consumerType.getQueue().getName();
            Function actionFunction = consumerType.getActionFunction();

            executorService.submit(new RPCConsumer(channel, queueName, actionFunction));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: No, reflection won't help you. Your example code is also full of suspicious untyped `ConsumerType`s. It's a bit unclear what you're trying to do, but if you are hoping for a "generic do anything" type of system, that won't work.

Answer (score 0):

#### First problem: raw types

```
public ConsumerType(RPCQueue queue, Function actionFunction) {
    this.queue = queue;
    this.actionFunction = actionFunction;
}
```

The argument type should be `Function< T, R >`.

```
public Function getActionFunction() {
    return actionFunction;
}
```

The return type should be `Function< T, R >`.  Those type parameters are bound by the class declaration.

```
private List<ConsumerType> consumerTypes;
```

I figure you want a heterogeneous list here.  That would be `List< ConsumerType< ?, ? > >` and this is where you are going to have a hard time.

#### Second problem: heterogeneous lists

Generic types exist only at compile time, and only to check things which can be statically checked.  A heterogeneous list of `ConsumerType` of arbitrary types will by definition not be statically type checkable.  However, the following should work:

```
public class RPCConsumer<T, R> extends DefaultConsumer implements Callable<Void> {

    private Channel channel;
    private String queueName;
    private Function<T,R> function;

    public static < T, R > RPCConsumer< T, R > make( Channel channel, String queueName, Function<T, R> function) throws IOException {
        return new RPCConsumer< T, R >( channel, queueName, function );
    }

    public RPCConsumer(Channel channel, String queueName, Function<T, R> function) throws IOException {
        // Constructor
    }

    // METHODS ETC

}
public class RPCConsumerFactory {

    private List<ConsumerType<?, ?>> consumerTypes;
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    public RPCConsumerFactory(List<ConsumerType<?, ?>> consumerTypes) throws NoHealthyServiceException {
        this.consumerTypes = consumerTypes;
        this.executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(consumerTypes.size());
    }

    public void createRPCConsumers() throws IOException, TimeoutException {
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        for(ConsumerType<?, ?> consumerType : consumerTypes) {
            Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

            String queueName = consumerType.getQueue().getName();
            Function<?, ?> actionFunction = consumerType.getActionFunction();

            executorService.submit(RPCConsumer.make(channel, queueName, actionFunction));
        }

    }
}
```